# How to make lazy regex search prioritize one match over another?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Given a string such as `"happy days"`, I would like to be able to match "days" as a top priority and stop matching if I get it. IF I don't I would like to match "happy" and whatever comes after it. So for example `"happy dogs"` would return the match "happy dogs" while `"happy days"` will just return "days". I thought of trying something like `(days|happy\s*\w*)?`. The idea was that 'days' was placed first and would quickly match and exit (since we are in lazy mode). But instead, it matches the full "happy days". How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you have to consume input string first with a greedy dot then make engine to backtrack:

```
^.*(days|happy\s*\w*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/EGKSms/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use negative lookahead:

```js
console.log("happy days".match(/days|happy(?!.*days.*).*/)[0])
console.log("happy dogs".match(/days|happy(?!.*days.*).*/)[0])
```